# Android ProgressDialog.show not showing up

Tags: android, android-event

I have the following code. When I put it in the ACTION_DOWN it works, when I put it in the ACTION_UP is doesn't, what am I doing wrong?

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            //it works here
             // progress = ProgressDialog.show(ExampleAct.this,"Processing...","Preparing file", true);

        } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              //It doesn't work here
              progress = ProgressDialog.show(ExampleAct.this,"Processing...","Preparing file", true);
            //Other code here is working fine
        }
        return true;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `ACTION_CANCEL` in the case of `ACTION_UP`.

Maybe the parent of `button1` intercept the TouchEvent. And the child will get `ACTION_CANCEL` instead of `ACTION_UP`

```
    button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                //it works here
                // progress = ProgressDialog.show(ExampleAct.this,"Processing...","Preparing file", true);

            } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    ||event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
                    ) {
                //It doesn't work here
                progress = ProgressDialog.show(ExampleAct.this,"Processing...","Preparing file", true);

            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: I forgot to add one thing, I actually have other code and it's fine inside the ACTION_UP block

Comment: btw, the code you provided has a bug, ProgressDialog will be called twice, one for ACTION_UP and one for CANCEL